PostgreSQL insert only if the new value is different from the old one
In Postgres, I have a telemetry table like this:
        time         |     name     | slave_id |       type       | fCounter
---------------------+--------------+----------+------------------+----------
 2024-05-14 11:20:30| FoobarCounter | 1        | holding_register |      101
 2024-05-14 11:20:20| FoobarCounter | 1        | holding_register |      101   <<--
 2024-05-14 11:20:10| FoobarCounter | 1        | holding_register |      100
 2024-05-14 11:20:00| FoobarCounter | 1        | holding_register |      100

Telegraf by default inserts a new row every 10 seconds, but the real measured value (stored in fCounter) updates once every few hours. So I want to throttle inserts to the DB, storing only new (updated) values and time, when it happened.
First of all, I create new table:
CREATE TABLE foobar_counter (
    time timestamp without time zone,
    value bigint NOT NULL
);

Then I create a funnction:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function(timestamp without time zone, text, text, text, bigint)
    RETURNS VOID
    AS $$ INSERT INTO foobar_counter VALUES  ($1, $5) $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;

and a trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON modbus
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (foobar_counter.value IS DISTINCT FROM NEW."fCounter")
    EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_function();

But it fails with error:
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "foobar_counter"
LINE 4:     WHEN (foobar_counter.value IS DISTINCT FROM NEW."nCounter...

and I'm actually not sure if this is the easiest/appropriate way
UPD
Up to this moment, the "last value" (in the fCounter column) was simply incremented. So the "unique index" solution was sufficient.
Today I found out that the counter can be reset to 0. Thereby, the actual definition for the "new value" is "the value different from previous record"
Postgres version: PostgreSQL 15.6 (Debian 15.6-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

Your trigger would not "throttle inserts to the DB". It would insert an additional row to another table (if the syntax was fixed). Please clarify your objective. Define "new value" exactly. As compared to the most recent row, or to all rows? Compared how exactly? Declare your version of Postgres.

crete a unique index  on   (name, slave_id , type, fCounte)
And use
insert into telemetry (name, slave_id, type, fCounte) 
VALUEs ( 'FoobarCounter' . 1 , 'holding_register' , 101)
on conflict do nothing;

to insert new data, this would prevent, that you insert duplicate data on these four columns.
you cpuld also think about normalising your structure
that would not account if the values wouldchage after again to 100
so a BOFRE INSERT trigger would be better
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  "time" TIMESTAMP,
  "name" VARCHAR(13),
  "slave_id" INTEGER,
  "type" VARCHAR(16),
  "fCounter" VARCHAR(10)
);



CREATE FUNCTION onlynewones() RETURNS trigger AS $onlynewones$
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW."fCounter" = (SELECT  "fCounter" FROM table1 
                             WHERE "name" =  NEW."name" 
                             AND "slave_id" = NEW."slave_id"
                             AND "type" = NEW."type"
                             ORDER BY "time" DESC LIMIT 1) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'fCounter already exists';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$onlynewones$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ONE_Add_NEW_Values BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION onlynewones();

INSERT INTO table1
  ("time", "name", "slave_id", "type", "fCounter")
VALUES
  ('2024-05-14 11:20:00', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '100');



INSERT 0 1


INSERT INTO table1
  ("time", "name", "slave_id", "type", "fCounter")
VALUES
    ('2024-05-14 11:20:10', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '100');



ERROR:  fCounter already exists
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function onlynewones() line 9 at RAISE


INSERT INTO table1
  ("time", "name", "slave_id", "type", "fCounter")
VALUES
  ('2024-05-14 11:20:20', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '101');



INSERT 0 1


INSERT INTO table1
  ("time", "name", "slave_id", "type", "fCounter")
VALUES
  ('2024-05-14 11:20:30', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '101');


ERROR:  fCounter already exists
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function onlynewones() line 9 at RAISE


SELECT * FROM table1




time
name
slave_id
type
fCounter




2024-05-14 11:20:00
FoobarCounter
1
holding_register
100


2024-05-14 11:20:20
FoobarCounter
1
holding_register
101




SELECT 2


fiddle
If you add multiple rows , you need to return null
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  "time" TIMESTAMP,
  "name" Text,
  "slave_id" INTEGER,
  "type" text,
  "fCounter" Integer
);



CREATE FUNCTION onlynewones() RETURNS trigger AS $onlynewones$
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW."fCounter" = (SELECT  "fCounter" FROM table1 
                             WHERE "name" =  NEW."name" 
                             AND "slave_id" = NEW."slave_id"
                             AND "type" = NEW."type"
                             ORDER BY "time" DESC LIMIT 1) THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$onlynewones$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ONE_Add_NEW_Values BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION onlynewones();

INSERT INTO table1
  ("time", "name", "slave_id", "type", "fCounter")
VALUES
  ('2024-05-14 11:20:00', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '100'),
('2024-05-14 11:20:10', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '100'),
('2024-05-14 11:20:20', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '101'),

  ('2024-05-14 11:20:30', 'FoobarCounter', '1', 'holding_register', '101');



INSERT 0 2


SELECT * FROM table1




time
name
slave_id
type
fCounter




2024-05-14 11:20:00
FoobarCounter
1
holding_register
100


2024-05-14 11:20:20
FoobarCounter
1
holding_register
101




SELECT 2


fiddle

@JGH now where you mention it, that is correct, so i added a trigger solution

I vote for the idea with unique. The trigger example proposes to introduce a race condition: the check in the trigger allows concurrent inserts to use duplicate values because they'd see the same snapshot. 2. Exceptions are expensive, custom exceptions complicate error handling. 3. That's effectively a constraint trigger 4. Please don't use varchar(n).

i know about the TEXT as prefered string type, but for purpose of demonstrating this will suffice, as the user didn't specify a table definition,, The constraint trigger isn't necesary in my opinion, but feel free to post your own anseer

Exactly my point. Making the inserts bounce off a unique constraint would suffice, plus it's short, quick and elegant. Since you already presented that, there's no point in posting a separate answer to show the same thing - I'd just upvote that and leave but the trigger examples you keep adding are just long and incorrect. If I were to edit it, I'd simply roll back to version one and clean up the typos/formatting, but that'd be quite intrusive. So instead I'm leaving a comment saying the opening's right, the rest isn't - it's up to you which way to go with the edits.

the data can not be used with a unique constraint if he gets `2024-05-14 11:23:10| FoobarCounter | 1        | holding_register |      100`` as only teh date is different an i have no cloue what was the last value, so how would you define a unique constarint that would capture the problem

According to OP's example, new value is indicated by fCounter, so the unique is only supposed to guard that one column. If fCounter is only unique in combination with name, slave_id, type, then you can add those to the constraint - which I thought is what you assumed in your opening example. Since neither variant lists time in the unique list, any difference in date or time of day is ignored and rejected if it comes with duplicate fCounter (and whatever else is in the unique list).
